# How to place two fixed divs on top of the page?

Tags: html, css

I have a header that is fixed to the top of the page, and I would like to add a "banner" above it (with a close icon). So the user can remove the top banner, and just see the header.

I can do it in the following way, but then if a user closes the banner, the header is positioned wrongly. (I would like the header to be sticky on top: 0; in case the banner is closed.) Is there a pure CSS solution for this (no JS)?

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: #f00;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.main {
  background-color: #ff0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 120px;
}

.banner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #f0f;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">This is the banner that can be closed (X)</div>
<div class="header">This is the header</div>
<div class="main">
  content<br> content
  <br> content
  <br> content
  <br> content
  <br> content
  <br> content
  <br> content
  <br> content
  <br> content
  <br> content
  <br> content
  <br> content
  <br> content
  <br> content
  <br> content
  <br> content
  <br> content
  <br> content
  <br> content
  <br> content
  <br> content
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Well how do you implement the closing of the banner?

Comment: @andreas probably with cookies, and display: none;

Comment: if you want a pure CSS solution you can use a container div that is fixed, your banner and header following the flow and then adapting places when banner is hidden or showed. However, i don't know how you will remember banner is clicked without JS, il will be always present at loading then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve that problem. Put header and banner in one parent that is fixed. Added animation to closing just to make it nicer.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('banner')[0].onclick = function(){
    this.classList.add('closed');
}
```

```css
.top{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.header {
  background-color: #f00;
  height: 100px;
}
.banner {
  background-color: #f0f;
  height: 120px;
  transition: height .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.banner.closed {
  height: 0;
};
.main {
  background-color: #ff0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="banner">This is the banner that can be closed (X)</div>
  <div class="header">This is the header</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
</div>
```

Comment: As for the part about js, you can't handle events (click) without it, so that's the bare minimum you are going to need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wrapper around the headers. The wrapper is fixed, headers are not. With `flexbox` you can position them in a column, and if one is closed (first one) the next will jump to the top. Heres the example snippet:

```js
$('.banner').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.wrapper__fixed {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f00;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.main {
  background-color: #ff0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 120px;
}
.banner {
  top: 0;
  background-color: #f0f;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper__fixed">
<div class="banner">This is the banner that can be closed (X)</div>
<div class="header">This is the header</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
    content<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Im gonna ignore the fact that the answer is similar to mine, but including jquery to make a simple click handler seems completly ridiculous.

Comment: @vicbyte I didn't saw your answer when I was writing mine sorry for that... And the JS snippet is just pure demo for removing the banner. The main topic was, how the second banner can jump to the top when the first disapears, and the CSS solution works for this case not mather how the banner was removed. Also upvote for your answer!